# How to properly initialize a storage array?

Tags: solidity

What's the correct right hand side expression for initializing a storage array of `address`?

I'm trying to initialize a `storage` `address[]` from inside a function. Everything I've tried gives warnings, and I'm looking for the correct way to silence them.

```
// address[] storage b;
Warning: Uninitialized storage pointer.
```

This warning is warranted. After testing I've found `b` is pointing to "garbage data" which happens to be the same as another `address[] storage a` array I define earlier. ([Related post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/35557/3118)) On top of that, modifying `b` (`b.length = 0`) is modifying the `a` array.

Every right hand expression I've tried hasn't worked, since they're meant for `memory` arrays. (eg. `= address[]()`)

Answer (score 2):

Although it doesn't directly address what you're asking, I think https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/03/09/understanding-ethereum-smart-contract-storage/ will help.

When you just declare `address[] storage b;` (same as without `storage`, since that's the default), `b` points to slot 0 in storage, which will be whatever state variable you declared first.

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, it's hard to suggest a fix, but you probably want to use a `mapping` or array in the contract scope (e.g. `mapping (uint256 => address[])` or the like).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A workaround I've found is to move the declaration to the top, as a state variable. It's strange though, and I feel there *must* be a way to initialize it in a function.

Comment: If you declared it in a function, how would you use it later?

Comment: It's to test a library function which consumes a storage array.

Comment: Ah, hopefully you can appreciate why that's a use case that's not worth optimizing for. Anyway, just use a `mapping`. E.g. `index = 0; mapping (uint256 => address[]);`. "Allocate" new dynamic arrays via `address[] storage b = mapping[index++];`.

Comment: Yeah, of course. Just a matter of curiosity and completeness :) About this solution, is it something you've used yourself as well? It's an interesting workaround.

Comment: I've used something similar to "allocate" nodes for a linked list. You can also `push` onto a dynamically-sized array.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I've found is to move the declaration to the top, as a state variable.

```
contract Test {
  address[] a;
  address[] b;

  function testFeature() {
    // test
  }
}
```